# GCP Failed load job, how to get the source json

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, load, jobs

I have some LOAD job in Google Cloud Platform, with an error like:

"Error while reading data, error message: JSON parsing error in row starting at position 0: No such field..."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plw5n.png)

So... since I got many failed jobs, I'd like to get that JSON that was unable get parsed, so I could fix it and upload again the job.

Is it possible to get that "source" json with all the data that was uploaded to the job?

Cause I'm only able to get the job info, but not the original json with errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6c6g.png)

Thanks

I'd tried to get the job original failing json, but I only got the job json description/result.
I need to get the source, so I could fix the json and re-upload the job.

Comment: Where are located your file? in cloud Storage? Do you submit the file directly by code?